# Missing parameters in firebase automatic event for google Analytics

Tags: firebase, mobile, analytics

According to the google documentation (https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9234069?hl=en), when the "Google Analytics for Firebase SDK" is used in an mobile application (which is the case) the FCM related events (notification_dismiss, notification_foreground, notification_open and notification_receive) are automatically collected to Google Analytics.
It is also noted that those events have the following parameters (message_name, message_time, message_device_time, message_id, topic, label, message_channel, message_type)

In my case, those 4 events are automatically collected but all previously mentioned parameters are absent (Android and iOS). But if I send the push notifications through the firebase console, those parameters are present (I tested it with a test message and the Debug View).

For the backend, we use the Firebase Admin SDK and for the React Native frontend we use https://rnfirebase.io/

We currently have the 7.3.0 version for Firebase Admin and the 14.12.0 version for all necessary @react-native-firebase packages (I also tested with the most recent versions backend + frontend and I had the same issue)

In this post ([Firebase event not display on firebase console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47587835/firebase-event-not-display-on-firebase-console)) we read "Only message sent through the Notifications panel in the Firebase console automatically log analytics events. For (either data or notification) messages that you send through the Firebase Cloud Messaging API, no analytics events are automatically logged.". In practice we see that it works partially as the analytics events are well displayed in the firebase debugview, which makes this statement wrong.

Would anyone know why these parameters aren’t collected when I send a FCM message from the backend?

Is there a source that proves that only notifications sent from the firebase console are working to trigger those Analytics events automatically and completely?

May I be sure it's not a configuration / bug / license issue?

Comment: got any solution to this ?